# と followed by a comma

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-と, punctuation, coordination

In the following sentence

> イタリアの理論物理学者フェルミ（Enrico Fermi ）は，この現象を，原子核の崩壊を引き起こす力**と**，力を媒介する未知の**粒子**の存在を仮定することで説明しようとした。

I guess the と followed by a comma means an exhaustive and. But an and of what? I guess of 粒子. Are there grammatical rules to determine this? Or is it just semantics?

Answer (score 3):

> 原子核の崩壊を引き起こす力と，力を媒介する未知の粒子の存在を仮定する

This means:

> Assuming the existence of [(原子核の崩壊を引き起こす)力] and [(力を媒介する)未知の粒子]

---

If there is no comma, it can be read as:

> Assuming the existence of [(原子核の崩壊を引き起こす and 力と力を媒介する)未知の粒子]

or

> Assuming the existence of 〈[{(原子核の崩壊を引き起こす)力と力}を媒介する]未知の粒子〉